# Can I use ReactTransitionGroup for creating transitions on update?

Tags: reactjs

Looking at the [component docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), react components has three items in their lifecycle: `mount`, `unmount` and `update`. [React transition groups](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) seems to be the most common way to apply transitions and animations in react. Can it be used on update aswell, (ie statechange) or only when an item is mounted/unmounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add transition on state change. You need to provide a key to the child element which will change on state update.

From [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) :

> You must provide the **key** attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

Thus, you can do something like this :

```
class Container extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        number: 0 
    };
  }

  handleClick(e){
    this.setState({number: this.state.number + 1});
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                <div className="number" key={this.state.number}>{this.state.number}</div>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Css

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

[Here is fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/g5bcg74q/83/)

Comment: nice, does the key enforce a new mount?

Comment: No. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed. I updated the question.

Comment: I see, in one instance I want to transform an element to center, I calculate the position and scale with javascript, can this be done in combination with react transitiongroups? style.transform = 'translateY(' + elem.offset + 'px) scale(' + elem.scale + ')'

Comment: I don't think so. You can maybe do it with css class and inline style. Add inline style `style={transform: ..."}` to that element and add also a class. And then in css add `transition: all 2s;` to that class.